# Override back press react native router flux

Tags: javascript, react-native, onbackpressed, react-native-router-flux

I am using react native router flux in my react native app. I want to override the back button press event as I want to add confirmation popup before going back. I have searched a lot but all the links I found was for overriding hardware back button press of Android. I not only want to override the hardware back press but also want to override the back button press event in the navigation bar (for both Android and iOS). Please help me out here.

**Edit:** I found one way to override the back press event by adding two props in my scene `back` and `onBack`. But now problem is I want this backpress to be conditional. I am passing a boolean prop `edit` to this scene. If the edit is true then only I want to override the backpress otherwise I just want the default one. So how can I change the Scene parameter in my Router.js using the props being passed to that scene?

sudo code

```
if(edit){
   openConfirmationDialog();
} else {
   Actions.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright! I found the way to it.

From wherever I am opening this scene I can pass onBack callback like this `Actions.Home({onBack: () => console.log('custom back callback') });`

This way I can provide dynamic back callback every time I open that scene.

Comment: Did you find any solution where you can access the fields or the props of the called actions in order to check for some conditions?

Comment: how to know if the user has pressed back from top bar??  from component ???

Answer (score 5):

To me, the above solution by @Raj Suvariya worked but only if I added a 'renderBackButton' callback to the scene whose 'onBack' I wanted to customize (the 'Home' scene in Raj's example):
So this was added to the scene's definition:

```
renderBackButton={()=>{}}
```

And this was added upon navigation to the page, same as in Raj's answer above:

```
Actions.Home({onBack: () => console.log('custom back callback') });
```

Answer (score 4):

**React Native | react-native-router-flux | Redux | Android Back button listener ,handle back press on android while using react native.**

```
// below code works with Android + react native + react-native-router-flux
// this is final index.js file code from where control whole app navigation
import { BackHandler, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Router, Scene, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// as per your compoenents import them accordingly
import Home from './home';
import OtherScreen from './OtherScreen';
//variable 
var backButtonPressedOnceToExit = false;

export default class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress.bind(this));
    }

  onBackPress() {
        if (backButtonPressedOnceToExit) {
            BackAndroid.exitApp();
        } else {
            if (Actions.currentScene !== 'Home') {
                Actions.pop();
                return true;
            } else {
                backButtonPressedOnceToExit = true;
                ToastAndroid.show("Press Back Button again to exit",ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                //setting timeout is optional
                setTimeout( () => { backButtonPressedOnceToExit = false }, 2000);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router backAndroidHandler={this.onBackPress} >
            <Scene key="root" }>
              <Scene key="Home" component={Home} initial={true}  />
              <Scene key="OtherScreen" component={OtherScreen}  />
            </Scene>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourAppNameAccordingToPackageJSON', () => App);
```

Comment: i used same like this sample also

Comment: delete your android.bundle.meta from assets and try to build again,

Answer (score 0):

face this problem too, but i did not add `onBack` in props as Raj post, if you have many places to override ,it will be very annoying to add onBack prop. What i do is to override RNRF's default onBackPress function.

```
//App.js

    <Router
        scenes={scenes}
        createReducer={reducerCreate}
        getSceneStyle={getSceneStyle}
        backAndroidHandler={() => {
            let cs = Actions.currentScene;
            if (cs === 'sc1' || cs === 'sc2') {

            } else {
                // default, pop back
                Actions.pop();
            }
            return true;
        }}
    />
```

```
    //component1.js, "component1" is a key in scenes registered.

    handleBackAction = () => {
        if (Actions.currentScene === "component1") {
            // do something you want and return true to intercept back event.
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackAction);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.backHandler.remove();
    }
```